# How to remove all navigable strings from a soup object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to remove all navigable strings and leave only tags in a soup object?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features="html.parser")

    for child in soup.descendants:

        if child.name:
            print(child.name)
```

Ouput

```
html
head
title
meta
body
h2
p
ul
li
li
li
li
li
```

Comment: Actually I am looking to remove the Navigable strings objects that appear when I create a soup object. What I mean is: soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser") should return only tags no navigablestring object.

Comment: @CS_EE Updated the answer. I hope you can use some modification of this. I can't think of any other way. Good luck with the answer.